# Print View file from controller for Ajax purpose in Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am working on cart function in codeigniter. I have worked under module named 'bookings' where I have placed cart view file in modules/bookings/views/shop/cart.php

When Something triggers, I have called update_cart function of bookings controller. All logic are ok, updating cart is also OK but, I need to re-show cart details after successfull ajax call.

My update function in bookings controller is like this

```
public function update_booking_cart()
{
    if($this->input->post('rowid') && $this->input->post('qty'))
    {
        $rowid=$this->input->post('rowid');
        $qty=$this->input->post('qty');
        $data = array('rowid' => $rowid, 'qty' => $qty);
        $this->cart->update($data);
    }
    else {

    }
    echo $this->template->write_view('shop/cart');
}
```

I am stuck in LINE `echo $this->template->write_view('shop/cart');`.... What to write in this line so that I get only shop/cart.php contents printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your method like this

```
public function update_booking_cart() { 
.... // your code 

// if there is some data to be sent add data in argument else leave 
// it blank or dontpass it
   $this ->load->view('shop/cart', $data); // this will return the view as response data
}
```

In ajax call make the following changes

```
$("#updatecart").click(function() { 
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  "your url like modules/bookings/update_booking_cart",
        data: { id: this.id },
        success: function(response) {
            $("#container").html(data); 
            // load the view data/html in your container
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ECHO the partial view as data to make AJAX catch the response:

```
public function update_booking_cart()
{
  // your code...

   echo $this->load->view('shop/cart', $data, true); // <-- third parameter
}
```